# Scilab - problem with plot3d2, flag not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: plot, graphics, scilab

When I write:

```
clear;
close();
close();
close();
X=[1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4];
Y=[1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2; 3 3 3 3; 4 4 4 4];
Z=zeros(4,4);
plot3d2(X,Y,Z); //, flag=[2,0,3]);
```

I get a black mesh filled with a blue surface (see left part of picture).

However, when I try to control it in more detail and unblock the part which is commented out in the last line of this code, all I get is an empty box (right part of picture).
#scilab #plotting #graphics #colors

[image: Results of either version of the code]

Curiously enough, when I first execute the code without the flag, and then, without closing the graphics window, do plot3d2 again *with* the flag, the surface changes colour according to the first element of the flag. But I cannot get rid of the black mesh - which is my main reason for trying to use flag.

Answer (score 1):

The `flag` option seems broken. Use the fields of the entity just created to change its rendering properties:

```
X=[1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4];
Y=[1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2; 3 3 3 3; 4 4 4 4];
Z=zeros(4,4);
plot3d2(X,Y,Z);
gce().color_mode=-2
```

See the description of the `color_mode` field at https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/surface_properties.html. Here `-2` means flat color 2 (in the current colormap) without the mesh:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
plot3d2(X,Y,Z, flag=[-2,2,3]);
```

works. Nothing is broken. Using flag(2)=0 requires having plotted something before. This is documented in the `plot2d3` page @ https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/plot3d2.html :

*type=0:
the plot is made using the current 3D scaling (set by a previous call to param3d, plot3d, contour or plot3d1).*